# Top 1 Row with Count

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a Query with the following output

```
SELECT  BIN_NAME,ROW_NUMBER() Over(Order by BIN_NAME) C
FROM USR_BINS_ITEMS I 
LEFT JOIN USR_BINS B ON I.BIN_COD=B.BIN_COD 
WHERE I.LOC_ID='6' 
And I.ITEM_NO = '364001'
```

And the  output is....

```
Bin     c
--------------
E1-03   1    
E1-08   2    
E2-01   3
```

---

However I would like my output to be

```
E1-03   ,  3
```

Which means, Select FIRST Row Bin Value only BUT show total row Count (or Max value from column C) as well. I am using MS SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you just want:

```
SELECT MIN(BIN_NAME) as BIN_NAME, COUNT(*) AS BIN_COUNT
FROM ...
```

Comment: OMG, I been trying with all possible joins and sub-queries totaly forgot about your simple solution :)

Comment: That's okay.  I think we've all been there!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 BIN_NAME, X.TOTAL
FROM USR_BINS_ITEMS I

LEFT JOIN USR_BINS B
ON I.BIN_COD = B.BIN_COD

INNER JOIN (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS TOTAL
    FROM USER_BINS_ITEMS I2
    WHERE I2.LOC_ID = '6' And I2.ITEM_NO = '364001'
) X ON TRUE

WHERE I.LOC_ID = '6' And I.ITEM_NO = '364001';
```

It requires that the search be performed twice, but it should be more performant than using a subquery (`SELECT BIN_NAME, (SELECT COUNT(*) ...) AS TOTAL ...`) assuming that the query planner is not smart enough to optimize that case.

Either way, this query should perform quite well and meet your requirements.

Note that without an `ORDER BY` clause, the database engine is free to return to you any row it wishes from the result set.  Add an `ORDER BY` clause if you want to get some specific row.

Comment: I had to make adjustments to your query to get it to work, what you you think about performance?

Comment: SELECT TOP 1 BIN_NAME, X.TOTAL 
FROM USR_BINS_ITEMS I 
 
LEFT JOIN USR_BINS B 
ON I.BIN_COD = B.BIN_COD 
 
INNER JOIN ( 
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS TOTAL, I2.ITEM_NO
    FROM USR_BINS_ITEMS I2 
    WHERE I2.LOC_ID = '6' And I2.ITEM_NO = '364001' 
    Group by I2.ITEM_NO
) X  on X.ITEM_NO=I.ITEM_NO
 
WHERE I.LOC_ID = '6' And I.ITEM_NO = '364001'

Comment: What doesn't work about this query with my version?  The changes you've made should not affect query output at all.

Comment: Inner join was missing "ON" Clause.

Comment: Odd, the `ON` clause is supposed to be optional.  I've updated my answer to include a dummy `ON` clause -- try that?  All my query is trying to do is generate a cartesian product; no join condition is necessary.

Comment: You could have used a CROSS APPLY instead of a JOIN to add columns to each row of the result without using an ON condition.  But, this problem didn't really require any of this, since no other columns were needed besides the minimum value and the count.